# How to reshape images of the dataset for keras?

Tags: keras, input, conv-neural-network, shapes

i want to build a covid-19 cnn detector from x-ray images with keras and my input shape is `(224,244,3)`
but i dont know how to change my dataset images to that size can't find specific resource for that
and also i watch many youtube videos all of them put 3 channels for x-ray photos (for the input shape) while it is black and white  can any one explain

i am using google colab

Comment: As far as I have understood you have images of size `(224,244,3)` so you want to convert it to `(224,224,3)`?

Comment: no i have different images with diffrent sizes and my model input should be (224,224,3)

Comment: so i need to resize all my dataset images to (224,224,3)

Comment: I have just posted an answer. Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I assume your dataset images is inside folder `images`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os, cv2
for image in os.listdir(os.path.join("images")):
  img = cv2.imread(os.path.join("images",image))
  img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224,3))
  cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("images", image), img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I assume you have the images with different shapes, now in order to achieve size of (224,224,3) you need to follow below steps.

**Step-1**

define shape size in variable

```
IMG_SHAPE  = 224
```

**Step-2**

if you are using `flow_from_directory` method then pass `target_size` like below.

```
image_gen_train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,rotation_range = 40,width_shift_range=0.2,height_shift_range=0.2,shear_range = 0.2,
                                     zoom_range = 0.2,horizontal_flip = True,fill_mode = 'nearest')
train_data_gen = image_gen_train.flow_from_directory(batch_size = batch_size,
                                                     directory = train_dir,
                                                     shuffle= True,
                                                     target_size = (IMG_SHAPE,IMG_SHAPE),
                                                    class_mode  = "categorical")
```

**Step-3**

Now in convolutional layer of model architecture pass `input_shape` as below.

```
classifier = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE, 3)),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
        
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.32),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,activation= 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = "softmax")  
])
```